# Geolocation api/services

Tags: c#, geolocation

Currently programing C# methods to retrieve the following address information:

Latitude/Longitude based upon postal address
Latitude/Longitude based upon ip address
Postal Address based upon ip address
Postal Address based upon zip/postal code

Anyone know of any geolocation services/api's I can plug in to that can help with retrieving some of the above? I am based in Europe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google provide a great [Geocoding API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/). It supports JSON and XML.

Example: http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=true

The free version is limited to 2,500 geolocation requests per day.

Answer (score 0):

Postal Address based upon zip/postal code
Latitude/Longitude based upon postal address

you can use gmaps

Answer (score 0):

try this [Google Geo Kit](http://gglgeo.codeplex.com/)